# Empy lines at the end of a column

Tags: spacing

I get empty lines at the end of a column like in the picture. [image: Empty lines in the red box]

I use save-space commands are as follows:

```
\usepackage[all=normal, floats, bibnotes, wordspacing, charwidths, indent, lists]{savetrees}
\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter

\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}
\belowcaptionskip 0pt

\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S\@gobble}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{\S\@gobble}
\renewcommand{\appendixautorefname}{\S\@gobble}

\skip\footins 0.5\baselineskip %8.1pt plus 4pt minus 2pt
\floatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\textfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip
\intextsep 0.5\baselineskip 
\dbltextfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip  
\dblfloatsep 0.5\baselineskip 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\raggedbottom

\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}
```

I wonder why my save-space commands do not solve the problem in the picture.. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you think it *should* do in this situation? You have `\raggedbottom` active which means it won't stretch vertically to fill the space so there'll be gaps at the bottom when the page isn't full. Yes, it looks like there's room for that line, but in this case it cannot put it there, because it has a footnote (it appears) and there would be no room for the footnote on that page, and it tries to keep the footnote marker on the same page as the note. What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: Ah, because of the footnote... You are a genius!